# Is it safe to delete underlying blob store without calling delete_serving_url?

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it advisable to delete a blobstore/ GCS object without calling `delete_serving_url()` first?

Currently, I am calling `delete_serving_url()` before removing the object but not sure if it's an overkill as it seems GAE can be trusted to do the necessary cleanup.

The documentation is quite clear about calling `delete_serving_url()` if you want to stop serving (obviously). But when the intention is to delete the object as well, the documentation is not very clear about whether `delete_serving_url()` is a necessary step.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is safe. `delete_serving_url()` is an [App Engine API call](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/images/#get-serving-url) that is [not present](https://github.com/googleapis/google-cloud-python/issues/1295#issuecomment-165555282) on Cloud Storage API. They are designed to work independent of each other, thus, it will safe to assume that if you use Cloud Storage API to delete the blob but the serving URL still remains, nothing will happen. It will just become a broken link.